# canvas does not get appended to list

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have two dataUrls which I need to be displayed in a canvas and finally I want them appended to the Unordered List called, "piclist" . But I can see only 1 picture getting appended. Can someone tell me why the other picture is not getting appended.I also checked with a alert message whether the loop gets iterated twice and it does.But only picture is appended

```
  let datapo = {{datapo|safe}};
  for (var key in datapo) {
    //alert(key+" "+datapo[key]);

     var node = document.createElement("li");
     var d0 = document.createElement("div");
     var c = document.createElement("canvas");
     var c4 = c.getContext("2d");


     c.width  = 200; // in pixels
     c.height = 100; // in pixels


     var myImg = new Image;


     myImg.src = datapo[key];
     myImg.width = c.width;
     myImg.height = c.height;


     myImg.onload = () => { c4.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

     document.body.appendChild(c); // adds the canvas to the body element
     node.appendChild(c);
     document.getElementById("piclist").append(node);

     };


  }
```

Comment: Does `myImg.onload` get called twice as well? Are you sure that the base64 encoded images are both valid? It seems like one of the pictures might be malformed, preventing it from ever reaching a `loaded` state.

Comment: Yes it gets called twice . And both pictures have the same encoding because it is the same picture

Answer (score 1):

Same element cannot be appended twice in DOM, solution is to [clone](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp) the elements before inserting into a second place, see demonstration

```js
function myFunctionNotWorking() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Item");
  node.append(textnode);
  node.append(textnode);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").append(node);
  document.getElementById("myList").append(node); 
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);  
}

function myFunctionWorking() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Item");
  node.append(textnode);
  node.append(textnode.cloneNode(true));
  node.appendChild(textnode.cloneNode(true));
  document.getElementById("myList").append(node);
  document.getElementById("myList").append(node.cloneNode(true)); 
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));  
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to append an items to the end of the list.</p>

<button onclick="myFunctionNotWorking()">Add Items (not working)</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionWorking()">Add Items (working)</button>
```